# getting generics error when try to bind the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to bind the grid (Kendo UI) with user entered values in `TextBox`, but when I start the program, I get an error like this,

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Models.EmployeeDetails]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Models.ParentViewModel'.

When the user entered the value in `TextBox` and then presses the submit button, the entered value needs to show in the grid.

This is my model,

```
namespace KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Models
{
    public class TextBoxGrid
    {
        public string EnteredValue { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeDetails> employees;
    }   
    public class ParentViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeDetails EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
        public TextBoxGrid TextBoxGrid { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string ManagerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my controller (where i am binding the user entered value to grid)

```
namespace KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Controllers
{
    public class EnterValuesGridController : Controller
    {     
        public ActionResult Index( TextBoxGrid model)
        {
            return View(GetEmployee());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostValues(TextBoxGrid model)
        {
            TempData["enteringValue"] = model.EnteredValue;
            return View(model);                
        }
        public  IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> GetEmployee()
        {
            string enteredValueId =(string) TempData["enteringValue"];
            string managerId = "M" +enteredValueId;
            List<EmployeeDetails> empdtls = new List<EmployeeDetails>();
            EmployeeDetails em1 = new EmployeeDetails();
            em1.EmployeeId = enteredValueId;
            em1.ManagerId = managerId;
            empdtls.Add(em1);
            return empdtls;
        }
        public ActionResult Orders_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(GetOrders().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        private  IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> GetOrders()
        {
            return GetEmployee();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view where I am displaying the grid,

```
@model KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Models.ParentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }    
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostValues","EnterValuesGrid",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.TextBoxGrid.EnteredValue)    
    <input type="submit" name="Submitbutton1" value="Submit1" />    
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoPratapSampleMVCApp.Models.ParentViewModel>()    
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(s=>s.EmployeeDetails.EmployeeId).Filterable(false).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(s => s.EmployeeDetails.ManagerId).Filterable(false).Width(100);        
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "EnterValuesGrid"))
     )
  )        
}
```

Would anyone please tell me why I am getting this error. How can I resolve this one?

**EDIT :**  Changed postvalue method

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostValues(TextBoxGrid model)
    {
        TempData["enteringValue"] = model.EnteredValue;
        var viewmodel = new ParentViewModel
        {
            TextBoxGrid = new TextBoxGrid { employees = GetEmployee().ToList() }

        };

        return View("Index", viewmodel);                       
    }
```

when I submit the button it not showing the values in grid but its showing empty grid...

Answer (score 2):

Error, because model of your view is ParentViewModel, but you give its with

```
return view(GetEmployee);
```

IEnumerable, so not corresponding object for model of view.
I advice you do it as follow

```
 public ActionResult Index( TextBoxGrid model)
    {
        var viewModel = new ParentViewModel
        {
            TextBoxGrid = new TextBoxGrid { employees = GetEmployee().ToList()}
            //but first change TextBoxGrid Property from emplyees to employees{get;set;}, second from  return empdtls; to  return empdtls.AsEnumarable();
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

You must create PostValues view,, or change PostValues to Index, if its give you dublicat change you code as follow

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostValues(TextBoxGrid model)
    {
        TempData["enteringValue"] = model.EnteredValue;
        return View("Index",model);                
    }
```

Comment: I update my answer. But it depends your logic How you must modify, so I only can say that, the object of which you give the view it have to correspond with model of view(if your action is ActionResult or ViewResult etc.)

Comment: I need to return the method like GetEmployee() to the view for binding .. but if i written like this how can i return...

Comment: Many thanks .... half percent is complete one more doubt on this one when i entered value in textbox and press the submit button it is giving this error `the view 'PostValues' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations` would you pls tell the how can i rectify this one ..pls

Comment: You are welcome, I change my answer again.if it works for you, can you mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Sorry , i am getting this error The resource cannot be found.(http 404) one small doubt  do i need to call getemployee from postvalues ...method

Comment: Now I can't understand you code logic,, Where do you use TempData? I change my code again, perhaps it works for you:)

Comment: intially it shows the empty grid , but when the user entered the value in textbox and press the submit button the entered value is added to grid ..that's what i want

Comment: Well, now I have another question,, where did you select employees from database?

Comment: So, I was patient for your questions,, please create new question if you want. I answered your first question honestly.:)

Comment: many thanks for your patience, first I am not using any db here i am using custom list that I want to display in grid here

Comment: Ok, Where is your custom list, Where do you add this list content to List<EmployeeDetail> list for view, an d where do you add new employee detail to your static list of employee?:)) Thank you so

Comment: let us if you have free time [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34631/discussion-between-pratap-k-and-elvin-arzumanoglu)

Comment: Hi @pratapk,Nobody could answer your question:), because you asked second question in comments section. I advice you to ask new question